# Bitbucket Container 'Build' exceeded memory limit - When taking android build

Tags: android, docker, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I use bitbucket pipeline for build android app but every time i am taking memory limit error.

Error message:

> Container 'Build' exceeded memory limit.

Bitbucket yml file:

```
image: java:8

pipelines:
  branches:
    feature/*:
      - step:
          name: BuildApp
          caches:
            - gradle
            - android-sdk
          script:
            - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip
            - unzip -o -qq android-sdk.zip -d android-sdk
            - export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/android-sdk"
            - export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
            - yes | sdkmanager "platform-tools"
            - yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-29"
            - yes | sdkmanager "build-tools;29.0.2"
            - yes | sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"
            - yes | sdkmanager "extras;google;m2repository"
            - yes | sdkmanager "extras;google;instantapps"
            - yes | sdkmanager --licenses
            - echo "$KEY_BASE64" | base64 --decode > app/$KEY_FILE_PATH
            - chmod +x gradlew
            - ./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace
          artifacts:
            - app/build/outputs/**

definitions:
  caches:
    android-sdk: android-sdk
```

I tried to increase docker memory like this.

```
definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 7128

pipelines:
  branches:
    feature/*:
      - step:
          name: Build App
          size: 2x
```

This will actually double the build minutes. I want to avoid that.

My gradle properties

```
kotlin.code.style=official
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

Normally my project build times not short and not small project, using a lot of libraries and feature modules. i don't know how its effect memory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First we tried to increase docker memory size **7128mb**.

But with configuration, we allocated **7128mb** for the docker service. **This leaves only 1024mb for the build container**, which is not sufficient for the successful completion of the build.

We did reduce the docker service memory to **1024mb** as shown below.

```
definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 1024
```

But still we getting error.

We check which process is taking how much memory and what is causing the failure.

Here is the `ps -aux` output from build:

```
> .... root          78  2.3  1.1 4853812 381648 ?      Sl   07:47  
> 0:09 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//bin/java
> -Dorg.gradle.app....... root         314  182 12.2 10295652 3970496 ?    Ssl  07:47  13:00 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
> -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx4096m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser........... root        2744  145 11.0 10389720 3591488 ?    Sl   07:48   8:52
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -cp
> /root/.gradle........ ...
```

From the output above, java process has `-XX:MaxPermSize=4096m` which limits the process to go over the 4gb limit and the other java process is spun up without the limit (and has 4gb memory usage as well). These two processes use 4gb RAM each.

Therefore we try to lower `org.gradle.jvmargs` to 2gb.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

And added `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable.

```
script:
  - JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Finally we’ve got a successful build.

Comment: Hi, where did you add this final line?

Comment: add script part of bitbucket-pipelines.yml file

Comment: Can you please post the entire bitbucket-pipelines.yml file? Still a bit confused

Comment: @AbhriyaRoy I updated question now you can see whole yml file.

Comment: Thanks, @denizs I ran into some other problem. But the out-of-memory issue is gone now.

Comment: I think it is in "step" context

Comment: I think `JAVA_OPTS` is a key change there. Docker service has memory 1024 by default.